# How do I properly redirect outbound links with special characters

Tags: search, redirect

The search form on my website has a couple radio inputs for the user to select which source (all but one are external to the website) the search query should use.

I retrieve those inputs (search term and source as ) ;

```
function search_redirect_form() {
  if (is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['simple'] ) ) {
        if (isset($_GET['simple']) && $_GET['simple'] == 'dogpile') {
            $query = $_GET["s"];
            wp_redirect(esc_url_raw('theurl1'. $query));
            exit();
        } 
        if (isset($_GET['simple']) && $_GET['simple'] == 'askjeeves') {
           $query =  sanitize_text_field($_GET["s"]);
            wp_redirect(esc_url('url3' . $query));
            exit();  
         } 
    else { 
        $query =  sanitize_text_field($_GET["s"]);
        wp_redirect(esc_url($home_url . "?s=" . $query));
        exit();  
    }
```

When a user inputs a special character ((apostrophe, ampersand))
the remaining text of the query is often removed; For example: 
"earth wind & fire" just ends up as "earth wind"

From reading [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs), I thought esc_raw_url would be the most appropriate to use; but that still results in queries being butchered on the other search engines, namely with the ampersand (&) where the remaining part of the query is cut off. 
("Earth wind & fire" becomes "earth wind").

At this point, I'm sort of wondering because wp_redirect does additional escaping (via [wp_sanitize_redirect](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1283)), that this may be a bug; but I'm still rusty with php and not sure. This is also probably confounded that the other websites may escape/sanitize inputs slightly differently.

Questions:

1. Should I be escaping on the input itself instead of the 
   URL?) (around the "s" variable in my example);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after posting, I learned a couple things, most importantly, [that url encoding is done differently for paths and queries](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode/) and one of our search sources treats the search query as a path, so I had to use rawurlencode for the path; and urlencode for the others. This is why I was receiving inconsistent results from trying different search engines.

There are a few sanitization functions within [wp_redirect](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1205) as well.

```
function search_redirect_form() {
  if (is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['simple'] ) ) {
       if ( isset( $_GET['simple'] ) && $_GET['simple'] === 'dogpile') {
            $query = urlencode( $_GET["s"] )
            wp_redirect(esc_url('url1' . $query));
            exit(); 
        }
        if ( isset( $_GET['simple'] ) && $_GET['simple'] === 'altavista') {
            $query = rawurlencode( $_GET["s"] );
            wp_redirect(esc_url('url2'. $query .'/field/all/mode/all/conn/and/order/nosort'));
            exit(); 
        }
        if ( isset( $_GET['simple'] ) && $_GET['simple'] === 'askjeeves') {
            $query = urlencode( $_GET["s"] )
            wp_redirect(esc_url('url3' . $query));
            exit();  
        }
        else { 
            $query = urlencode( $_GET["s"] )
            wp_redirect(esc_url($home_url . "?s=" . $query));
            exit();  
        }   
  }
} add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_redirect_form', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try just removing anything that had the potential to alter your url.  I would suggest something like the following:

```
$str =  sanitize_text_field($_GET["s"]);
// Remove anything that is not: alphanumeric, slash, dash or space.
$query = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-\_]*/','',$str);
```